# Possible? or How to? clone Device properties from one USB controller to another?

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager, xbox360, game-controller

I have an issue with a wired Xbox 360 controller, showing Device Descriptor Request Failed, in device manager.

Now I have 2 controllers, one works fine, and both worked fine until recently, so I know it is not drivers, which I have already tried reinstalling multiple times.

Is it possible through some utility or program to copy the USB device properties from the working controller to the problem one? If the device is not identifying correctly, can I reprogram the controller somehow to have the right ID set from the working device?

Windows 10

Comment: Even if that were possible, it wouldn’t help: Your gamepad’s USB controller is most likely broken. It wouldn’t properly communicate even if you skipped getting the device descriptor.

Comment: So are you suggesting there is a hardware failure in the controller?
The lights flash as normal when plugged in, and the USB dev viewer shows activity.

Comment: Yeah, that’s how it is. You could of course also test its functionality on a different PC or with Linux or whatever.

Comment: For future reference is there a known utility for flashing a USB device ID to a piece of hardware?
I've found many USB sniffers and viewers at this point but nothing that allows flashing new registry information. Along the lines of the original question, there's no way to clone a USB device information properties to another, even the same, device? Such as from the working controller to the non-functional one.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if there is a hardware failure but would like to be able to designate the device properties back to their correct values so that I can associate the correct driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a USB host system software indicates that  "Device Descriptor Request Failed", it means that your device failed to respond to the very basic, initial USB transaction, to return valid descriptor information with correct USB protocol. This control transaction is the very first one in the process of USB enumeration. When this happens, it means that the host system already tried to get the descriptor at least nine times (under Android likely 288 or more times), and didn't get valid results. It usually means that the USB device is rock-solid dead. It may flash some LEDs, but the USB serial interface engine is likely plain dead. Sorry.

Regarding the second part of your question, no, there is no utility to flash VID/PID/descriptor/whatever information from one USB device to another. This information (at least most of USB required fields) is usually either hardcoded in silicon, or the entire device microcode/firmware (if any) must be flashed anew through some external debug process (because the main USB interface is dead).

Your Xbox controller likely has some broken/worn-out wires in the cable. Either throw it away, or check the cable data connectivity first.